# Simple use of 'defs' is not displaying anything

Tags: svg

I am a total noob at svg. Passed the basic syntax, I am struggling with the `defs` syntax.

Using Chrome to test the simplified use case:

This is working fine:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g><path id="red" fill="red"  d="M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 Z" stroke="black"/></g>
  <g transform="translate(200, 0)"><path id="blue" fill="blue" d="M10 10 H 60 V 60 H 10 Z" stroke="black"/></g>
</svg>
```

But this is not showing anything:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
        <path id="red" fill="red" />
        <path id="blue" fill="blue" />
  </defs>

  <g><use xlink:href="#red" d="M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 Z" stroke="black"/></g>
  <g transform="translate(200, 0)"><use xlink:href="blue" d="M10 10 H 60 V 60 H 10 Z" stroke="black"/></g>
</svg>
```

Assuming this is a simple oversight... Also, would that be better solved with `symbols`. I just read about both, but it was not obvious what was one better at than the other.

**UPDATE**

Based on Robert's comments, I fixed the missing `#`. Is there a way to make this code work with `g`roup instead of `path` being inside defs as in the code below?

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
        <g id="red" fill="red" />
        <g id="blue" fill="blue" />
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#red"><path  d="M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 Z" stroke="black"/></use>
  <use xlink:href="#blue" ><path d="M10 10 H 60 V 60 H 10 Z" stroke="black"/></use>
 </svg>
```

Comment: use elements can't have children.

Comment: Okay. So that is bad news. SVG is showing its age. And it's not from coming out of a semi structure root where HIERARCHY is at the center. How can't that be?

Comment: What do you mean by "showing its age"? You are trying to do the equivalent of `<img><div></div></img>` in HTML. You are trying to do things that it's not intended to do.

Comment: Maybe if you told us what you are trying to achieve, we may be able to suggest something. But at the moment it is not at all clear to me what it is you are after.

Comment: Thanks for offering. Essentially, I am trying to use a very rudimentary SVG parser (unable to cope with external links, css, etc...) to put some style tags in existing svg file. So I figure if I have defs of styles (e.g. fillcolor), I can reference them in the path or polygon shaped. But so far, `d` isn't supported and `g` won't work because of the hierarchy. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

use elements don't take d attributes so they would still need to go on the path elements.

Also your second use element is missing a # character in the xlink:href attribute.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
        <path id="red" fill="red" d="M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 Z" />
        <path id="blue" fill="blue" d="M10 10 H 60 V 60 H 10 Z" />
  </defs>

  <g><use xlink:href="#red" stroke="black"/></g>
  <g transform="translate(200, 0)"><use xlink:href="#blue" stroke="black"/></g>
 </svg>
```

Or just use a style tag with CSS. You may need to extend your rudimentary parser to cope with some simple CSS.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
        <style>
          .red {
            fill: red;
          }
          .blue {
            fill : blue;
          }
        </style>
  </defs>

  <path class="red" d="M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 Z" stroke="black"/>
  <path class="blue" d="M10 10 H 60 V 60 H 10 Z" stroke="black"/>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I updated my question while i am not able to move the xlink:refs up one level. Does that mean the group is closed before I use path even if the closing use is after the path element?